# How GIT manages the staging area

Tags: git

When we add a file to the staging area, it gets added to the objects sub-folder in .git folder. How does GIT differentiates between the committed files and the files present in staging area. It must store this information somewhere. Any insights?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 3):

This question is about Git Internals. Git records the differences occured between commits. You can learn more about it in this link.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects